# How do you make a 8 byte call in x64 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am trying to hook a function in a process that is 64 bit, the relative jump is over 4 bytes so I can't do it via normal methods. Is there any way to jump 8 bytes relative or absolute? Cheers if any examples!

Comment: Only indirect jumps are absolute. So load your address into a register and jump. Alternatively, put it onto the stack and `ret`. Note `push` also only takes a 32 bit sign extended immediate so you also need to do some work on that but that doesn't change a register.

Comment: Cheers! Is there an opcode for let's say jmp rax? and the value I want is loaded into rax?

Comment: I think it's FF D0. But do you need to move the relative address to the register? Or do you need to just mov the absolute to the register?

Comment: indirect jumps / call use absolute addresses, like function pointers.

Comment: FF D0 is call rax. FF E0 is jmp rax.

Comment: Thanks so much man!